# Ubuntu-22.04 File watcher failed repeatedly and has been disabled (External file changes sync might be slow)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wsl-2, ubuntu-22.04

I am starting to learn Java Spring Boot 3.0 and I am using IntelliJ Community Edition with WSL2 as OS. After I installed the most recent Update (2023.3.6) this warning appeared. And it seems that it is avoiding me from Load Maven Project.

[image: error message]

Other documentations make it look like the problem is with Ubuntu but before the update, everything was working.